# How to extract part of variable into another variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a variable which looks like xx-xx-xx-xx where each xx is a number (length of each xx is unknown)

I need to extract those numbers in separate variables to be able manipulate them.
I tried to look at regular expressions but couldnt see any solution (or i am just blind enough not to notice.

Ideally solution should look like

```
#!/bin/sh
# assume VARIABLE equals 1234-123-456-890
VARIABLE=$1

# HERE SOME CODE assigning variables $PART1 $PART2 $PART3 $PART4

echo $PART1-$PART2-$PART3-$PART4
# Output will give us back 1234-123-456-890
```

I am quite new to shell scripting so i might have missed something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `bash` you could use an array like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
VARIABLE=1234-123-456-890

PART=(${VARIABLE//-/ })

echo ${PART[0]}-${PART[1]}-${PART[2]}-${PART[3]}
```

The `${VARIABLE//-/ }` expansion changes all - to spaces and then it's split on word boundaries into an array.

Alternatively, you could use `read`:

```
#!/bin/bash
VARIABLE=1234-123-456-890

read PART1 PART2 PART3 PART4 <<< "${VARIABLE//-/ }"
echo $PART1-$PART2-$PART3-$PART4
```

To make it work in `sh`, you could change it slightly and set `IFS`, the input field separator:

```
#!/bin/sh
VARIABLE=1234-123-456-890

old_ifs="$IFS"
IFS=-
read PART1 PART2 PART3 PART4 <<EOF
$VARIABLE
EOF

IFS="$old_ifs"
echo $PART1-$PART2-$PART3-$PART4
```

Caveat: this was only tested with `bash` running in `sh` mode.

Comment: Thanks @FatalError, this is what i was looking for. I think i'd go for option with `read`.

Comment: If you use `IFS=- read a b c d <<< "$VARIABLE"` then you don't need to use the "old_ifs" temp variable because "IFS" will only be modified for the duration of the read command.

Comment: @glennjackman Neat! Didn't know about that one but it's going in my bag of tricks. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`/bin/sh` is [dash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) (see section "Parameter Expansion")

```
#!/bin/sh
# assume VARIABLE equals 1234-123-456-890

VARIABLE="$1"

PART4="$VARIABLE"       # PART4 is 1234-123-456-890

PART1="${PART4%%-*}"    # PART1 is 1234
PART4="${PART4#*-}"     # PART4 is 123-456-890

PART2="${PART4%%-*}"    # PART2 is 123
PART4="${PART4#*-}"     # PART4 is 456-890

PART3="${PART4%%-*}"    # PART3 is 456
                        # PART4 is 456-890

PART4="${PART4#*-}"     # PART4 is 890

echo "$PART1-$PART2-$PART3-$PART4"
```

Test for `$PART1-$PART2-$PART3-$PART4`

```
$ ./test.sh 1234-123-456-890
1234-123-456-890

$ ./test.sh 1234-abc-789-ABCD
1234-abc-789-ABCD
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PART1=`echo $VARIABLE | cut -d'-' -f1`
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
a="1234-123-456-890"
OIFS=$IFS; IFS=-; b=($a); echo "${b[*]}"; echo "${b[@]}"; IFS=$OIFS; echo "${b[*]}"
1234-123-456-890
1234 123 456 890
1234 123 456 890
echo "${b[0]}"
1234
echo "${b[1]}"
123
echo "${b[2]}"
456
echo "${b[3]}"
890
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "abc-def-ghi"|cut -f1 -d'-'
```

[more about cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29)